# How do I get two output variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, output

```
function [ surface_area, volume ] = cube_and_sphere_calculator( geometry,l_r )
if geometry == 1
   surface_area = 6 * l_r^2
   volume = l_r^3 
elseif geometry == 0
   surface_area = 4*pi*l_r^3
   volume = (4/3)*pi*l_r^3
else
   disp('you have to choose a value that is either equal to one if you want to calculate the surface area and the volume of a cube or equal to zero if you want to calculate the surface area and the volume of a sphere')
end
end
```

If I put semicolons after the formulas, matlab gives only one output variable: ans. This answer is equal to the surface area. I want two output variables, and I want them to be surface_area and volume. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

From the matlab documentation [Declare function](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html)

```
function [m,s] = stat(x)
n = length(x);
m = sum(x)/n;
s = sqrt(sum((x-m).^2/n));
end
```

And to call the function.

```
values = [12.7, 45.4, 98.9, 26.6, 53.1];
[ave,stdev] = stat(values)
```

So you call the function, the same way you write it.